# How can i create or use an svg file with velocity engine?

Tags: java, spring, svg, velocity

I use Velocity engine to generate a pdf file and I am trying to create a signature. I use a svg file for the signature and I want it to be part of my output pdf file. 
Therefore i first tried to integrate the svg in the velocity file(.vm), first by putting it inside an image and then by creating a new vm file and calling it from there, but these options don't seem to work.

When i try to include svg in the velocity file, inside image tags it is not recognized.